# There's many tab button in website and I want to click tab with name of "Claims" and it's sub tab of "Claims Research Tool"

Tags: vba

Eligibility and Benefits

Claims

below are my coding to hit tab button Claims but it's not working

```
Set AllSpanElements = myhtml.getElementsByTagName("a")
For elemntcount = 0 To AllSpanElements.Length
    With AllSpanElements(elemntcount)
        If .innerText = "Claims" Then
           .Click
           Exit For
        End If
     End With
```

Next

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Dim AllSpanElements As Object, element As Object
Set AllSpanElements = myhtml.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each element In AllSpanElements
    If element.innerText = "Claims" Then
          element.Click
    End If
Next
```

If the `innerText` condition does not solve your problem, try something different e.g. `ClassName` or `GetAttribute("name")`.

```
If element.ClassName = "whatever" Then
    element.Click
End If

'...

If element.GetAttribute("name") = "whatever" Then
    element.Click
End If
```